# Преобразование Map с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, java-hashmap

Имеется структура типа `Map<String, List<MyClass>>`.
Как с помощью Stream API преобразовать ее к типу `Map<String, List<MyClass.getField()>>`, где `MyClass.getField()` - некоторое поле класса `MyClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Получаем лист строк из листа объектов

Преобразовываем `Map<String, List<MyClass>>` в `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```java
class MyClass {
    String field;

    public MyClass(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("one", Arrays.asList(new MyClass("one1"), new MyClass("one2")));
    map.put("two", Arrays.asList(new MyClass("two1"), new MyClass("two2")));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        // собираем из исходной
        // карты новую карту
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            // ключ такой же
            k -> k.getKey(),
            // значение - из листа объектов
            // получаем лист строк
            v -> v.getValue().stream()
                // получаем значение
                // поля объекта
                .map(MyClass::getField)
                // собираем обратно в лист
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(map2); // {one=[one1, one2], two=[two1, two2]}
}
```

---

Если у нас `List<Object>`, то не обязательно собирать новую карту, можно преобразовать существующую, т. е. заменить значения в листе:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("one", Arrays.asList(new MyClass("one1"), new MyClass("one2")));
    map.put("two", Arrays.asList(new MyClass("two1"), new MyClass("two2")));

    map.forEach((key, list) ->
        IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i ->
            // получаем значение поля объекта
            // и заменяем им сам объект
            list.set(i, ((MyClass) list.get(i)).getField())));

    System.out.println(map); // {one=[one1, one2], two=[two1, two2]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот более прямолинейный и грубый вариант при помощи `forEach`:

```java
public class MapToMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> mySrc = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.addAll(Arrays.asList("asdf", "qwerty", "zxcvb"));
        mySrc.put("list1", list1);

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.addAll(Arrays.asList("asdf1234", "qwer12345", "zxcv12456"));
        mySrc.put("list2", list2);

        // Создаем переменную назначения
        Map<String, List<Integer>> myDst = new HashMap<>();

        // И здесь полностью проводим разбор и сохранение
        mySrc.entrySet().stream().forEach(elem -> {
            var myKeySrc = elem.getKey();
            var myValSrc = elem.getValue();
            List<Integer> myValDst = new ArrayList();
            myValSrc.stream().forEach(i -> myValDst.add(i.length()));
            myDst.put(myKeySrc, myValDst);
        });

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> elem : myDst.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(elem.getKey());
            for (Integer i : elem.getValue()) {
                System.out.printf("\t%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
list1
    4
    6
    5
list2
    8
    9
    9
```